# How do I animate and move a circle across a bezier path?

Tags: objective-c, uibezierpath

Hey so I'm pretty new to ObjC and coding in general. Essentially I want to make a circle move across a UIBezier path (close to a sin function) one 'unit' every hour and make its shadow small and yellow, then brigger and white, then small and dim again as it moves up and then down the curve. The crest of the sin function should be midday (noon), and the 'tails' of the curve should midnight on both sides. Is this even possible? And where can I find the resources to help me? Couldn't seem to find anything online to help me since I don't know what I need to achieve this. Thanks!

Comment: Most of this is well within the domain of Core Animation. Mike Nachbaur has a [nice series of Core Animation tutorials](http://nachbaur.com/blog/core-animation-part-1). Or google "Core Animation tutorial" and you may find tons of other hits. It will take you a little time to get your arms around it, but it's a good technology to familiarize yourself with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the CAKeyFrameAnimation class to move the view along a path. You create a path, and animate the position property of the view's layer. An example of this is in Apple's Core Animation documentation in the "Using a Keyframe Animation to Change Layer Properties" section. The other things you want to do with the shadow, can be done with CABasicAnimation. You can animate a shadow's color, offset, radius, path, and opacity.

Comment: Thanks for answering most of my questions! I'm trying to teach myself but it's not working out well

Comment: +1 FYI, `CABasicAnimation` is fine for animating along bezier path, too. But `CAKeyframeAnimation` may be useful in changing the color to and from a particular color as it moves along.